# Setup SQL Server replication for schema only or schema + nightly data

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql, replication

We have 2 offices that we would look to keep our databases in sync with.  Unfortunately one of our officers has a really poor connection and doing live SQL replication of the data probably isn't ideal.

The ideal situation would be live schema replication with nightly data replication.

If the ideal isn't possible strictly schema replication would be great.

Answer (score 0):

What is the amount of data changes for a given day? What is the version + edition of SQL Server? Please add more details to get decent responses.

You can synchronize schema by building something like below using DDL triggers.

http://thehobt.blogspot.com/2009/03/synchronizing-changes-to-stored.html

Comment: Link is blocked, "This blog is open to invited readers only"